# Magento catalogsearch/query collection returning same results on successive method calls

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to get Magento search result collection using catalogsearch/query model from outside of Magento. The search function below works without any issues for a single call. However successive method calls are returning the same collection. I've also tried loadQueryText() without any success. In the following code example, both $carSearch and $bikeSearch are loading results for the keyword "car".

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function search($keyword)
{
    $search = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($keyword);

    return $search->getResultCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');
}

// Search Car
$carSearch = search('car');
foreach($carSearch as $product):
     echo "<a href=\"{$product->getUrl()}\" title=\"{$product->getName()}\"><img src=\"{$product->getSmallImageUrl()}\" 
                alt=\"{$product->getName()}\" /> <br />{$product->getName()}</a>";
endforeach;

// Search Bike
$bikeSearch = search("bike");
foreach($bikeSearch as $product):
     echo "<a href=\"{$product->getUrl()}\" title=\"{$product->getName()}\"><img src=\"{$product->getSmallImageUrl()}\" 
                alt=\"{$product->getName()}\" /> <br />{$product->getName()}</a>";
endforeach;
```